# Footer appears at the bottom of modal pop up box

Tags: css

My footer appears fixed to the bottom of my modal pop up box, I typed in position:absolute; in the footer portion and it moved to the left of my page while the popup box was displayed. It looks like it is a child of the modal? I do not see my footer when the modal box is not displayed. I thought footer content was supposed to be at the bottom of my css/html/js files. Why is this happening?

```css
/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #869592;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Modal*/

.modal {
  display: flex-box;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #869592;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

p {
  font-family: input-mono, monospace;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fbff12;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.button-modal {
  display: flex-box;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  font-family: input-mono, monospace;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #aaa;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* FOOTER */

footer {
  font-family: input-mono, monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #869592;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.fa-github {
  color: #869592;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-github:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
    <!--- The Modal --->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Game Over!</p>
        <button id="newGame"> Restart Game </button>
      </div>

  </body>

  <footer>
    COPYRIGHT &copy
    
    <script>
      new Date().getFullYear() > 2010 && document.write(+new Date().getFullYear());
    </script>
    
    <! -- github icon --!>
    <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
    </a>
  </footer>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the HTML? Sounds like the footer is part of the modal -- maybe you forgot to close a `</div>` or something in the modal

Comment: Sure! I added the HTML below, thank you

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>`. You also don't need the `!` on the end of a comment tag. It's just `<!-- comment -->` Here's an HTML validator: https://validator.w3.org/ If you're ever unsure as to why your code isn't working, run it through that to check for errors.

Comment: Wow, should have caught that! Thank you so much for the comment and for the validator link. I did not know about that!

Comment: No problem, happens to everybody! :)